What adjective describes a boastful, lying man?
A boastful person is one who talks too proudly about himself and his abilities, achievements or possessions. But what about those who lie or exaggerate about themselves? For example, I say, 'I am an excellent chess player, I can beat all of you', when you know that I am just an ordinary player. What adjective can use for this person? Someone who claims is better than others, but not. In this situation, everyone knows that he's lying, and he knows that everyone else knows.

bullshit
(usually vulgar)
Merriam-Webster says:

bullshit intransitive verb
to talk foolishly, boastfully, or idly

Wikipedia explains it further:

In philosophy and psychology of cognition, the term "bullshit" is sometimes used to specifically refer to statements produced without particular concern for truth, clarity, or meaning, distinguishing "bullshit" from a deliberate, manipulative lie intended to subvert the truth.

So, someone who brags that they're excellent at chess when everyone knows they're not is bullshitting.
Note: This is a highly informal term, and is often considered vulgar, so use it with caution.

Grandiose usually implies exaggeratedly pretentious, but I quite like...

braggadocious
praising yourself or speaking too proudly about your own achievements or importance  (Cambridge Dictionary)

